# Does Azure ever cache old versions of views in an app service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops

A view called SideBar.cshtml view was moved from ./ to ./shared. I get the expected results without error on my local instance of IIS express. I built and released via Azure Dev Ops but when I navigate to the page in question I receive the following error and the page fails to load.

```
SideBar.cshtml(6): error CS1061: 'SideBar' does not contain a definition for 'InvitationsActive' and no extension method 'InvitationsActive' accepting a first argument of type 'PeopleHubSideBar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The property in the error above called InvitationsActive was renamed to EnrollmentActive post-move. So, to me its as if azure is looking at the old view in the old location. The repository Azure DevOps is correct so I know its nothing with the code as it exists on my local.

I have tried restarting the app service to no avail. I was thinking that Azure somehow cached the old view, but I do not see anyway to clear the cache. Any help would be useful.

Comment: maybe a dumb question but are you sure it's azure and not your browser? have you tried running incognito? I've never seen azure itself cache a view without me setting that up but that doesn't mean it doesn't happen either :)

Comment: Not a dumb question but yes I've tried in multiple browsers - incognito and/or clearing browser cache does not seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by fully qualifying the call to Html.Partial. Still not sure of the root cause but I hope this helps someone!

Not working

```
@Html.Partial("SideBar", sideBar)
```

Working

```
@Html.Partial("../Shared/SideBar", sideBar)
```